# Extract integral parts from strings in dataframe columns of lists

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

If I have a column data such as:

```
           value
1    [a_1, a_342, a_452]   
2    [a_5, a_99]   
3    [a_482, a_342, a_452, a_888]
```

I need to trim that column to:

```
           value
1    [1, 342, 452]   
2    [5, 99]   
3    [482, 342, 452, 888]
```

Basically, I want to remove `a_` and make each entry of the column become a list of integers

I tried using `replace` and `map` function based on **pandas python package** but none of this works.

For a single entry in a column such as:

```
    value
1    a_1 
2    a_5  
3    a_99
```

I can use something like `df['value'] = df['value'].str[2:].astype(int)`, however, this doesn't work with the lists of strings above.

Really appreciate if you can give my any suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

To make life easy, just convert to `str`, use *`str.replace`*, and apply *`ast.literal_eval`* on the result.

```
import ast

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).str.replace('a_', '')\
           .apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in ast.literal_eval(x)])
df 

                  value
1         [1, 342, 452]
2               [5, 99]
3  [482, 342, 452, 888]
```

---

**Option 2**

Using *`df.extractall`*

```
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack()\
                              .apply(lambda x: list(x.dropna().astype(int)), 1)
df 

                  value
1         [1, 342, 452]
2               [5, 99]
3  [482, 342, 452, 888]
```

---

```
df['value'].tolist()
[[1, 342, 452], [5, 99], [482, 342, 452, 888]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
#get list of strings
df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).str.findall('\d+')
#convert them to ints
df['value'] = [[int(i) for i in x] for x in df['value']]
#alternative
#df['value'] = [list(map(int, x)) for x in df['value']]
print (df)
                  value
1         [1, 342, 452]
2               [5, 99]
3  [482, 342, 452, 888]
```

Solution with list comprehensions:

```
import re

df['value'] = [[int(re.findall('\d+', i)[0]) for i in x] for x in df['value']]
print (df)
                  value
1         [1, 342, 452]
2               [5, 99]
3  [482, 342, 452, 888]
```

Alternative:

```
df['value'] = [[int(re.search('\d+', i).group()) for i in x] for x in df['value']]
```

And solution with `replace` in regex by `sub`:

```
df['value'] = [[int(re.sub('[_a]', '', i)) for i in x] for x in df['value']]
```